# How to add button next to some column in datagridview depending on condition

Tags: forms, winforms, c#-4.0, windows

I want to add button next to autocomplete textbox in datagridview. But that button will be added only if the data is not populated in autocomplete textbox. I want to add that data in the table on click of that added button otherwise that button wont be shown to user.
I have added autocomplete textbox in datagridview but dont have any idea about how to add button dynamically next to this textbox.

Comment: What do you have so far. Please create (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `data is not populated in autocomplete textbox`? I will asume that the autocomplete source is not set, if its not that correct me.

Does it need to be dinamic? It's one button or multiple?

If it does not need to be dinamic, you can add the button on the designer and set its `visible`to false.

And when you want to check for the button to be or not to be visible just:

```
button1.Visible=textbox1.AutoCompleteSource == null;
```